# lock rows so others can't modify them using Postgres and SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to make a query to a Postgres database then somehow lock the returned rows so that other SQLAlchemy threads/processes cannot modify those rows. In the same session/transaction of the query, I'd like to update the rows I received from the query and then commit the changes. Anyone know what to do?

I tried implementing a query with the `with_for_update(nowait=True)` function, but this throws an `OperationalError`.  I could catch this exception and simply the query again, but I'd like to offload this to the db if possible.

I'm using:

- Postgres 9.4.1
- SQLAlchemy 1.0.11 (ORM)
- Flask-Restful
- FlaskSQLAlchemy

I'm prepared to use straight SQLAlchemy if it's not possible with FlaskSQLAlchemy.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL? Why do you need `NOWAIT`?

Comment: I edited the version number into the question. As for ``NOWAIT``, I set it because when I didn't have it, the transaction would hang. Atleast I got feedback when it was present.

Comment: Well then that just means whatever row you wanted to lock is already locked.

Comment: ``I could catch this exception and simply the query again, but I'd like to offload this to the db if possible.``

Comment: Yes, and the way you do this is to not specify `NOWAIT`, in which case the DB will wait until the row is unlocked.

Comment: I see. Then I must be doing something wrong in the implementation of Sqlalchemy. I'll post the code once I'm back in the office.